# Xcode shows swift errors while editing despite compiling

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I'm getting lots of `undeclared type` errors in the Xcode editor in Swift files (not Objective-C), despite the code running fine when I actually compile it. For example, my app delegate (not changed from the template):

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain // 'NSApplicationMain' class must conform to the 'NSApplicationDelegate' protocol
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate { // Use of undeclared type 'NSApplicationDelegate'

    // Methods

}
```

It's the same throughout the project, eg. my view controller says `NSViewController` and `NSTextView` are undeclared identifiers. I've tried cleaning, clearing derived data, and the usual stuff. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html) :

`NSApplicationDelegate` needs an import statement `import AppKit` This may solve your problem.

Comment: Why the default templates can't just have the correct libraries I do not know! I changed `import Cocoa` to `import AppKit` in all files relating to Cocoa and everything works.